# How to delete Element In MongoDB property's array with MongooseJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I cannot remove an element inside of an array that is a property of a MongoDB Model.
*Please remember this is a NodeJS module **mongooseJS** and not the real MongoDB so functionalities are not the same..*

GOAL: Delete an object from the *statusLiked* array. | **I have also confirmed that the value of status.id is correct.**

Model:

```
 Const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  myStatus: Array,
  statusLiked: Array,
 )};
```

Delete:
 1. Deletes the status(works). 2. Delete the status from User.statusLiked(no work).

```
exports.deleteStatus = (req, res, next) => {
  var CurrentPost = req.body.statusid; // sends in the status.id
  Status.remove({ _id: CurrentPost }, (err) => {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    // vvvv this vvv
    User.update( {id: req.user.id}, { $pullAll: {_id: CurrentPost }, function(err) { console.log('error: '+err) } });

    req.flash('success', { msg: 'Status deleted.' });
    res.redirect('/');
  });

};
```

What happens: The specific status(object) is deleted from the database. But the status still remains in the User.statusLiked array.

What I want to happen: **Status to be deleted from the User.statusLiked array and the status to be deleted from the database. Then, reload the page and display a notification.**

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work somehow. Working code:

```
exports.deleteStatus = (req, res, next) => {
  var CurrUser = req.body.userid;
  var CurrentPost = req.body.post;
  Status.remove({ _id: CurrentPost }, (err) => {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    console.log('meeee'+CurrentPost+'user: ' +CurrUser);
    req.flash('success', { msg: 'Status deleted.' });
    res.redirect('/');
  });
User.update( 
      { _id: new ObjectId(CurrUser)},
      { $pull: { myStatus : { _id : new ObjectId(CurrentPost) } } },
      { safe: true },
      function (err, obj) {
        console.log(err || obj);
      });
};
```